# Como creo un jar ejecutable de un proyecto que contiene JavaFX

Tags: javafx, maven, jar, scenebuilder, mysqlconnector.jar

He creado un jar ejecutable solo lo puedo ejecutar desde la consola de comandos con sus argumentos de eclipse.
**java --module-path "D:\javafx\javafx-sdk-16\lib" --add-modules javafx.controls,javafx.fxml -jar Autolavado.jar**
Entonces quiero saber como hacer para poder distribuider la apliacion y que los usuarios solo la ejecuten, si alguien tiene un ejemplo para hacer esto con maven o gradle y pudiera escribir mas informacion.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar un plugin para delegar en [jpackage](https://programmerclick.com/article/19912065183/) la creación de un ejecutable. Si estás usando módulos, eso permitirá no tener que meter TODO el JRE en ele ejecutable.

El plugin es este: https://petr-panteleyev.github.io/jpackage-maven-plugin/

Un ejemplo de cómo configurar el plugin (necesita configurar el maven-jar-plugin para generar los ficheros en una única carpeta):

```
<plugins>
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <outputDirectory>target/jmods</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
    
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>copy-dependencies</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>copy-dependencies</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <includeScope>runtime</includeScope>
                    <outputDirectory>target/jmods</outputDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>

    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.panteleyev</groupId>
        <artifactId>jpackage-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
            <modulePath>target/jmods</modulePath>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
</plugins>
```

No hay mucha documentación en español, lamentablemente.